# Ways of representing "half-way" between applying a homeomorphism?

Tags: polar-coordinates, parametrization

Something I am particularly interested in is finding a potential way to create an animation illustrating smoothly how points in one 2D space map to another. In particular, I would like to show students how points in Cartesian coordinates become mapped in polar coordinates.

I'd love to be able to recreate this animation [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system#/media/File:Cartesian_to_polar.gif), which illustrates how the curve $y = \sin 6x+2$ becomes transformed to $x = \sin 6y + 2$, and then to the polar equation $r = \sin6\theta + 2$.

I know how to map the points from the second form into the third form mathematically, but what I'd like to be able to do is mathematically derive the result of applying the homeomorphism part-way through, as between the start and end points of the animation. Is it possible to parametrise a "semi-image" under the transformation from Cartesian to polar with some parameter, say $t\in [0,1]$?

I will admit homeomorphisms isn't something I know very much about, so any general ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you familiar with **homotopy**?

Comment: @Noah: I am interested to know what homotopy between $z$ and $e^z$ you have in mind for the animation?

Answer (score 1):

The transformation you're looking for is
$$ \pmatrix{x\\y} \to \pmatrix{x+y\sin(px)-px \\ y\cos(px)} $$
Notice when $p=0$ we have
$$ \pmatrix{x\\y} \to \pmatrix{x \\ y} $$
and when $p=1$
$$ \pmatrix{x\\y} \to \pmatrix{y\sin(x) \\ y\cos(x)} $$
So when $p$ is inbetween $0$ and $1$ we have a coordinate system "inbetween" Cartesian and Polar.

Note that this doesn't include a diagonal reflection.

Here is a quick demonstration in Mathematica code:

```
f[x_] := Cos[6 x] + \[Pi]/2
Manipulate[
 ParametricPlot[
  {x - p x + f[x] Sin[p x], f[x] Cos[p x]}, {x, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}, 
  AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotRange -> 5],
 {p, 0, 1}
 ]
```

Another example in Desmos:
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/1ezxpbihfa

and one in javascript:
http://thevaportrail.com/js/gfx/CartToPolar.html?S=2